# CSS - Overlay hover text over another article

Tags: html, css, hover, overflow, overlay

I'm working with wordpress and I want to customize my own template. But I stuck on little problem. On hover of div *post-redakce* I want to show the rest of text. It works good but there is problem that I need text overlay next article section which is bellow.

Here is my complete code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rLta/1/) where in the second article you can see full text on hover but the first arctile can't overlay second article. Thank you very much, answer in JSFiddle would be best.

It's wordpress so each article begins with:

```
<article id="post-id" class="post-id post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-nezarazene post-redakce">
```

Comment: I can't see your issue

Comment: When you hover the second article then you see that text bellow is already visible but when you hover the first article then the text (lorem ipsum...) is hide behind the second article and that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set bigger z-index on hover

```
.post-redakce:hover {
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew that there is just some small problem :-)